# Why jQuery tag question are not showing?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, stack-overflow

Why are jQuery tagged questions not showing?

I get an empty list:

[image]

What is going on in SO?

Comment: Cache reload or something like that probably.

Comment: It was the same for [tag:Perl], but both are fixed now.

Comment: it wasnt working for me too ..but now its working :)

Comment: The meta site (all questions) did the same thing for me for a few moments.

Comment: My custom search went blank for a moment too; just a small glitch, we can get on with our answering now.

Comment: Not yet fixed http://i.stack.imgur.com/hPp2h.png [tag:javascript] :(

Comment: @TusharGupta: And now it is. It’s looking pretty temporary. :)

Comment: @minitech yeah hope they fix it fast :)

Comment: People have finally figured out how to use Google, and are asking no more questions. We are witnessing the beginning of a new era.

Comment: [LOL we really dont need jquery question like this anymore](http://img180.imageshack.us/img180/3305/addanumbertoanothernumb.png)

Comment: Maybe there was 1 bad jquery question too many and it got burninated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was an issue with the tag engine back-end that serves these question lists.  We'll be investigating this failure a bit more Monday (crazy fluke after weekend processes it looks like), but have restarted the services for now and have  3 redundant servers in play.

Comment: So [meta-tag:status-completed] means you found the issue causing this and fixed it? :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd we made some additional changes to prevent it, yes - though during a full TE outage it can still occur.  It's a simple setup, but the tag engine itself is tremendously complex to achieve what it needs to do so at that level of performance.  Also, it's not *just* the tag engine really, it's StackServer which hosts our core web project remotely across app domains also including things like related question rebuilds, search indexing, etc.

Comment: Cheers Nick, good enough for me and guess for everyone else!